# Data storage for an iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storage

I am writing an application that has all the buildings on my campus and in a tableview. When you click a building it will retrieve info on it such as the longitude, latitude, building name, and an image of it.

My question is what do you think is the best way to store this data? Should I used sqlite3 database or maybe Core Data? Sqlite3 is what I am leaning towards right now, I'm somewhat familiar with SQL. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

CoreData uses SQlite. If you're into learning, that would be your best bet, since all apple-related things (iphone, ipad, ipod touch and MacOS X all have support to it).

There are lots of books and examples on how to use CoreData. Also, CoreData can handle updates do your database in a nice way.

To use CoreData, you don't need to write any line of SQL. Its all done for you by the API.

Comment: I'd put it more strongly;  Unless you have a very specific need for portability to non-Apple platforms *or* you really, *really*, want to learn SQL, SQLite is a waste of time compared to Core Data.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll look into it more. I was leaning towards sqlite3 because I could just write a perl script that would take all the info for each building and place it in a table. I'm not sure if it would be just as easy to do for CoreData. I've messed around with CoreData a little bit and it is very easy and friendly to use.

Comment: You can write import routines for CoreData, but you should generally do it from within your app. Directly accessing the underlying CoreData's SQlite database is not recommended.

Answer (score -2):

OK, so i figured out a great way to do this using Core Data. I created the Core Data model with an entity and its attributes. The entity and its attributes correspond to a table and its columns. I ran it and it created an empty sqlite file. You can find this file in:

> /Users/[name]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/[some long HEX number]/Documents

from there, you can open and view the sqlite file and its contents by typing:

```
> sqlite3 [name of file].sqlite
> .schema
```

.schema shows the tables and columns. You notice that when Core Data creates a sqlite database, it will call the table Z[entity] and the columns Z[attribute] where entity is the name of your entity and attribute is the name of your attribute. So the table and all the attributes have a Z preceding it.

I then wrote a script to gather all the information and store it in this database which I then put back in the directory I found it from and it worked! Hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem I did.

I definitely suggest using Core Data over SQLite, Core Data is much easier to use.

**UPDATE:** I should mention that I used this to initialize a database and not make any changes to it after the initialization.

Comment: Please do not do this. Accessing the underlying Core Data database is a TERRIBLE idea. Apple can change the actual implementation at any time and your app will fail. Just use the actual Core Data methods to create your data.

Comment: This is fine for debugging, and perhaps to initialize some standard data ONCE, but you should not rely on it.

Comment: In my case, I needed to initialize a table that contained the data of 230 buildings, each with different attributes. There would be nothing changed in the database after that, so I don't see how there could be problems. How does Apple expect you to automate a process of storing huge amounts of data without accessing the underlying database directly and using Core Data?

Comment: It is very easy to write an import routine to do this using Core Data. Regardless, if you are going to do this then stick to David's advice. I would still advise against it though. At the very least writing the import routine will familiarize yourself with the ins and outs of writing Core Data apps. One of the things to really understand about Core Data is that it is not a database. It can use SQLite as a storage mechanism, but it can also use XML or other formats. People who have a hard time with Core Data are the people who can't wrap their head around this. Anyway, best of luck to you!